# Canvas iframe application with multiple pages

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am trying to figure this out. I have a canvas iframe application with multiple pages. How can I have a user authorise the application, and then have a specific page show up when they load the application again, this being unique to them?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the signed request that is passed to your application to determine if the user has authorized your application (you'll have a user id if they have) and then make the appropriate logic decision to display whatever page you want.

You'll need to do this with backend code as the `signed_request` is sent as a post to your server. Do a search on the Facebook developer site for `signed_request` and [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) 2.0 and that should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Dustin. I will look into those links. I forgot to add, is it then possible to show the newly redirected page to that users friends, keeping note of the original users ID ?

Comment: When the user authorizes your app you get access to their friends but you'll need to ask for additional permissions to communicate with them.  I'd suggest posting to their wall as the friends should be able to see that without your app being looked at as spam.